# Spring Boot bootrun taking infinite time. The application is stuck in bootrun

Tags: java, mysql, kotlin, connection

I created a blank new projekt with spring initializir in intellij.

after that i just edit application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springserverdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.username=master
spring.datasource.password=j21983d23d9sad+o
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

the login data is just to test.

this is my build.gradle , i added the mysql-connector-java

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
}

group = "com.setserver"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33")

}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

my SQL server is running
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFQR1.png)

database is created by me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RQiN.png)

also i created the useraccount
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RQde.png)

but when i boot the programm in intellij its stuck on

> at com.setserver.setserver.SetserverApplication.main(SetserverApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
>
> 2024-02-20T18:58:51.185+01:00  WARN 15760 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQL8Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
> 2024-02-20T18:58:51.186+01:00  WARN 15760 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
> 2024-02-20T18:58:51.390+01:00  INFO 15760 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
> 2024-02-20T18:58:51.394+01:00  INFO 15760 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> 2024-02-20T18:58:51.419+01:00  WARN 15760 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
> 2024-02-20T18:58:51.640+01:00  INFO 15760 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
> 2024-02-20T18:58:51.644+01:00  INFO 15760 --- [           main] c.s.setserver.SetserverApplication       : Started SetserverApplication in 3.057 seconds (process running for 3.289)

before is edit it, it was running but with errors

Comment: The application started as expected in 3.3seconds, you can see that in the log:

`o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '' 2024-02-20T18:58:51.644+01:00 INFO 15760 --- [ main] c.s.setserver.SetserverApplication : Started SetserverApplication in 3.057 seconds`


Have you tested port 8080 if your controllers are available, since the Spring context was successfully created, your application is technically up and running.

Comment: EDIT, sry you are right, i thought there will come something like "Succufully booted" , may i remembered it wrong. Anyway thanks for that fast Answer!